# PATH variable using eclipse differs from system variable

Tags: eclipse, processbuilder, path-variables

This little java code produces different output dependend on execution environment:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd", "/c", "set" );
builder.directory( new File("c:/") );
Process p = builder.start();

System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
```

If executed on command promt it will state the full PATH variable which is also shown by navigating to Systenproperties->Environmentvariables (PATH) or using cmd, typing in set, and looking up for the PATH variable.

```
Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin;
```

If executed in eclipse it will also state the a PATH variable but it is not consitent with the one in the system itself.

```
Path=C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\eclipse;
```

The issue is, i need to run an external application (openssl) in my java environment using a processbuilder. The path of that application is also stated in the Path variable. But this path is not available if the code is executed by using eclipse (which is a must in this case).

So i have absolutely no clue why this is the case and how to solve it.
I even tryed to stream the executing class to the hdd and try to execute that class using another processbuilder, but still the Path variable is not equal to the expected one (guess due to inheritance)

Please, if some of you guys have any clue how to get the same content of the Path variable using eclipse as the system itself does, point it out.

btw. Using a WINDOWS machine & using Kepler build

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the output of the `PATH` when run under Eclipse and when run from the command prompt?  Is Eclipse picking up an older value of the `PATH` variable?  Is Eclipse adding its own stuff to the `PATH`?  Also, which version of Eclipse are you using?  I've just tried with Eclipse Indigo (a bit old, I admit) and I have been unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: yes, thank you! Added the information to the question. It seems that eclipse changes the original value

Comment: Are you replacing the values of any environment variables in your Eclipse run/debug configurations?  (This is on the Environment tab of the Run Configurations/Debug Configurations windows.)

Comment: No, i dont change anything in run configurations

Comment: I've just downloaded and started using Eclipse Kepler and have noticed it adding the JVM stuff to the front of the `PATH` and the Eclipse location to the end.  However, it hasn't taken bits out of the `PATH`.  Silly question, perhaps: has Eclipse been restarted since you installed OpenSSL?  If Eclipse was started when the `PATH` didn't have the location of OpenSSL in it, then any processes it starts will also have their `PATH` lacking the OpenSSL location.

Comment: Failing that, you can use the Environment tab of the Run/Debug Configurations windows to add the location of OpenSSL to the `PATH`.

Comment: silly question, indeed! But rebooting solved the issue :/ Thanks A LOT!